# Place an element right above another element with unknown height and position:fixed

Tags: css, css-position

I have the following element:

```html
<div class="bottom-est">Bottom-Est</div>
```

```css
.bottom-est {
  position: fixed;
  width:100%;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

Can I place another fixed position element right above it?

**If** it has a fixed/known height, I can just add `bottom:##px` to displace it:

```html
<div class="bottom-ish">Bottom-Ish</div>
```

```css
.bottom-ish {
  position: fixed;
  width:100%;
  bottom: 18px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Which will accomplish the resulting goal:

[image: Screenshot of Goal]

But is there a way to do this that doesn't require knowing the height ahead of time.  I can't modify `.bottom-est` at all, but I can modify `.bottom-ish` as much as I want.

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.bottom-ish {
  position: fixed;
  width:100%;
  bottom: 18px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.bottom-est {
  position: fixed;
  width:100%;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="bottom-ish">Bottom-Ish</div>
<div class="bottom-est">Bottom-Est</div>
```

Comment: Will they always be the same height?

Comment: And could you add common a parent element to both of them? And I'm assuming you don't want to use javascript?

Comment: @MichaelCoker, no the heights of both are variable.  Their only comment parent is `body` without JavaScript, which could give me the element height anyway without shuffling around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With CSS alone, the answer is NO.

Once you apply `position: fixed` to an element you remove it from the document flow. This means that other elements don't respect the fixed element's space. In fact, they treat the fixed element as though it doesn't even exist.

So unless you know the height of the fixed element, you can't position another element to stack right above it.

Answer (score 1):

An addition to [@Michael_B's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43332244/2827823) answer

To avoid script, there is 2 ways, a shared parent

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.bottom {
  position: fixed;
  width:100%;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: orange;
}

.bottom-ish {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.bottom-est {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="bottom">
  <div class="bottom-ish">Bottom-Ish</div>
  <div class="bottom-est">Bottom-Est</div>
</div>
```

or nested

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.bottom-ish {
  position: absolute;
  left: -1px;
  width:calc(100% + 2px);
  bottom: calc(100% + 1px);
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: yellow;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.bottom-est {
  position: fixed;
  width:100%;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: orange;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="bottom-est">
  <div class="bottom-ish">Bottom-Ish</div>
  Bottom-Est
</div
```